# Angular 2 Official Tutorial - Promise.resolve VS http

Tags: angular

In Angular 2's official tutorial, they use Promise.resolve(HEROES) to get the HEROES array.

I try following the Http Client tutorial but I encounter some problems. I **can** make the request, but when I navigate to other pages, it will make the get request again. Different components are using their own set of HEROES.

I would want to know why they will behave differently. If I want to communicate the server and still making the components to use the same set of HEROES, what should I do?

Tutorial Live Example: ( https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html )

My trial: ( http://plnkr.co/edit/mPgpt2snK2OY6o8sq6YK?p=preview )

What I make difference is that...

(1) Angular Official's version of **app/hero.service.ts**

```
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes() {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }

  getHero(id: number) {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES).then(
      heroes => heroes.filter(hero => hero.id === id)[0]
    );
  }
}
```

(2) My version of **app/hero.service.ts**

```
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  getHeroes() {
    return this.http.get("hero.json")
                    .map(res => <Hero[]> res.json().HEROES)
                    .do(data => console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

    getHero(id: number) {
    return this.http.get("hero.json")
                    .map(res => <Hero> res.json().data.filter(hero => hero.id === id)[0])
                    .do(data => console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError (error: any) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the error to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    console.error(error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
  getHeroes() {
    if(this.data) {
      return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else {
    return this.http.get("hero.json")
                    .map(res => <Hero[]> res.json().HEROES)
                    .do(data => {
                       console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
                       this.data = data;
                     });
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    };
  }
```

Comment: Yes thank you! I have update the link and it works. Can you explain more about the concept of Observable? (Or sending a starter guide is good) Once again, thanks!

Comment: `Promise` and `Observable` provide a unified API to work with async execution (to avoid callback hell). You can pass a callback to `Promise.then(...)` which is called when the async call (for example a request to the server) is completed. If you have a sequence of events where you want a callback to be called for each event, `Observable` is a better choice. Instead of chaining subsequent async calls with `then(...).then(...)` as with `Promise` there are a long list of all kinds of operators that can be used with `Observable`.

Comment: See for example https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md (Angular2 uses RxJS 5) or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHI0AzD_WfY for more details. There are lots of docs out there. Angular just uses RxJS and works well with it. RxJS is not part of Angular though.